# npm error when install react project in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm

Hi thanks for reading this topic 
I work with react I nowadays trying to learn `ReactJS` when install react new app show an error for uninstall react new project 
what is my problem

in `Command Terminal`

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
>   '...9.1","tslint-config
>   -p'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-12-26T01_36_25_1
>   39Z-debug.log `npm install --save @testing-library/react@^9.3.2
>   @testing-library/jest-dom@^4.2 .4 @testing-library/user-event@^7.1.2`
>   failed

Comment: I suppose that your `package.json` file is somehow malformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's version problem.

If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, we recommend you uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` to ensure that npx always uses the latest version

**Quick Start**

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

For more clarification check this [reactjs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem quite a few times.
Then used following commands, it worked for me

```
npm init
npm cache clean force
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```